# PHP's date functions: converting from weeknumber back to month

Tags: php, datetime

Given the information below:

- Year: 2012
- Weeknumber: 4
- Dayname: TUE

How can i convert this to a valid date like 2012-01-12 (YYYY-MM-DD) using PHP's date functions?

Thanx

Comment: See the [DateTime object](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Comment: Would your keyboard slap you if you search a bit the PHP doc ?

Comment: Is the week number an [ISO week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates)?

Comment: @Truth Sorry bud but there is no support for the `weaknumber` with the `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Comment: @VIPINJAIN: You multiply it by 7?

Comment: @Truth omg but this also does not solve the problem. This is more complex than this

Answer (score 4):

The `DateTime` class can't do this, but the function [`strptime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) can.

```
$d = strptime('TUE 4 2012', '%a %W %Y');
var_dump($d);
```

That returns an array:

```
array
  'tm_sec' => int 0
  'tm_min' => int 0
  'tm_hour' => int 0
  'tm_mday' => int 24
  'tm_mon' => int 0
  'tm_year' => int 112
  'tm_wday' => int 2
  'tm_yday' => int 23
  'unparsed' => string '' (length=0)
```

Note that `tm_year` contains the number of years since 1900 and `tm_month` is 0-based, not 1-based. So this does represent 2012-01-24, which is correct.

Comment: nice answer.. I didnt knew about this function. So i wrote a script:D check it out...

Answer (score -4):

Use this function:

```
function get_date($year,$week,$day,$start_sunday=false){
    $day_array = array('Mon'=>1,'Tue'=>2,'Wed'=>3,'Thu'=>4,'Fri'=>5,'Sat'=>6,'Sun'=>($start_sunday?0:7));
    $month_array = array(31,($year%4==0?29:28),31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
    $week *= 7;
    $month = 1;
    for($i=0;$i<count($month_array);$i++){
        if($week-$month_array[$i]<=0){
            break;
        }
        $week -= $month_array[$i];
        $month++;
    }
    $format = "$year $month $week";
    $date = date_create_from_format("Y m j",$format);
    $date_num = date_format($date,"D");
    $curr = $day_array[ucfirst(strtolower($day))]-$day_array[$date_num];
    $got_date = strtotime("$curr ".($curr==1||$curr==-1?"day":"days"),strtotime(date_format($date,"Y-m-j")));

    return $got_date;
}
```

where `$start_sunday` should be `true` if week starts from `sunday`

`$year` is the year
`$week` is week number
`$day` is short weekday name i.e.mon,tue,wed,....

this function will get you a date form the given format.

```
Enjoy............
```

Comment: -1 because it makes my eyes hurt. And there are more rules for calculating whether it is a leap year or not. And for not using built in functions to do the job.

Comment: yeep i know there r more rules for 100th year :P